# Batch ping website and get ip

Tags: batch-file, web, numbers, ping

I would like to get the ip address from a site (eg. google.com gives me 173.194.66.103), and i do this by pinging the website.

```
For /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('ping -n 1 www.google.com^|find "Pinging"') do set ip=%%a
pause
```

This works greatly in CMD, but when i type it in a batch file it doesn't load. And when i try to close the window i get the error:

**"The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.**

**^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C> was unexpected at this time.**

**'a' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"**

I believe it is the ping part, which gives the same error in batch when run seperately.

```
ping -n 1 www.google.com
```

Comment: Getting back on track, this code shouldn't be able to work in a command prompt; `%%a` is exclusively for batch scripts, while `%a` is required for the command prompt. Also, your code works perfectly for me and sets ip to 2607:f8b0:4006:806::1013. `^C` is from you hitting Ctrl-C to try and stop the script while it's running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code can be simplified to

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('ping -n 1 www.google.com') do set "ip=%%a"
```

There is no need for the `find` as the only line that will have a second token is the one with the square brackets.

But the problem persits. Why does it generate the indicated error?

The usual response is *Your batch file is named `ping.cmd`, `ping.bat`*, so, when you call `ping` from your batch file, the batch file is calling itself (or in your case and original code this will also happen with `find.cmd` or `find.bat`).

Rename the batch file (recomended) or change the command to call `ping.exe` (the same for `find.exe`) to avoid conflicts.

Comment: My batch was named `ping.bat` and when changed it worked

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that :

```
@echo off
Title Getting The IP address
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set myServer=www.google.com
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=[]" %%a IN ('ping -n 1 !myServer!') DO (
 if "%%b" NEQ "" set ip=%%b
)
echo The IP address of !myServer! is !ip!
EndLocal
Pause
```